# Free vector space and its quotient

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products

Given $\phi_1: V\times W \to F[V\times W]$ defined by $\phi_1(v,w)=(v,w)$, where $F[V\times W]$ is the free vector space. $\phi_2: F[V\times W] \to F[V\times W]/Y$ is defined by $\phi_2(v,w)=[(v,w)]$, where Y is so chosen that $\phi:  V\times W \to  F[V\times W]/Y ,\phi:(v,w) \mapsto [(v,w)]$, is linear. Then $\phi= \phi_1 \circ \phi_2$.

Questions:

Firstly, what can we say about the basis for the free vector space $F[V\times W]$ (in terms of the bases for $V $ and $W$)? I know this question may be a little stupid, but these stuff is from a linear algebra course and we haven't talked about things like free R-module yet. These maps are constructed in order to show $F[V\times W]/Y$ satisfies the universal property of tensor product.

Moreover, can we say any of $\phi, \phi_1, \phi_2$ is surjective? Given that not all elements in $F[V\times W]/Y= V\otimes W$  can be written as $v\otimes w= [(v,w)]$, I doubt if $\phi$ is surjective.

Answer (score 0):

All the pairs $(v,w)$ are a free basis for $F[V\times W]$ so an element $T\in F[V\times W]$ is a linear combination
$$T=\sum_{k,l} T^{kl}(v_k,w_l)$$
for certain scalars.
To construct $V\otimes W$ you need to quotient $F[V\times W]$ with the vector subspace $S$ generated by the relations
$$a(v,w)-(av,w),$$
$$a(v,w)-(v,aw),$$
$$(v_1+v_2,w)-(v_1,w)-(v_2,w)\qquad \mbox{and}$$
$$(v,w_1+w_2)-(v,w_1)-(v,w_2).$$
Then $v\otimes w=(v,w)+S$